# Saving and decrypting encrypted files with encryptr R-package

Tags: r, encryption, shiny, rsa

I have a shiny app where I want to store userdata on the server and want to encrypt it before storing it. I'd like to use the `encryptr` package for this but so far I can't make my solution work properly. What I've managed so far is to write the data as a rds file, then encrypt it and delete the unencrypted copy. Ideally however, I'd like to only store the encrypted file. However, when I try to decrypt it again, the file doesn't change at all.

```
#### Approach with storing file first (works)

# data
data <- mtcars

# saving file
saveRDS(data,"Example.rds")

# keys
genkeys()

# encrypting
encrypt_file("Example.rds")

# deleting unencrypted copy
file.remove("Example.rds")

# unencrypting file
data_decrypted <- decrypt_file("Example.rds.encryptr.bin")
```

What I would like to do instead is something like this

```
#### Approach with storing only encrypted file (can't be decrypted again)
    
# data
data <- mtcars
    
# keys
genkeys()

# encrypting data
data <- encrypt(colnames(data))

# saving encrypted data
saveRDS(data,"EncryptedData.rds")

# clearing wd
rm(data)

# loading encrypted data
EncryptedData <- readRDS("EncryptedData.rds.encryptr.bin")

# decrypting data
data_decrypted <- decrypt(colnames(EncryptedData))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the data parameter in your `encrypt/decrypt` calls and you are opening the wrong file name. Try

```
data |> 
  encrypt(colnames(data)) |> 
  saveRDS("EncryptedData.rds")

rm(data)

EncryptedData <- readRDS("EncryptedData.rds")
data_decrypted  <- EncryptedData |> decrypt(colnames(EncryptedData))
```

Note that we pass the data into encrypt. If you just run `encrypt(colnames(data))` without piping data into the function, you should get an error about "no applicable method ...an object of class character". I used the pipe operator `|>` but you could use regular function calls as well. Then, since you are writing to "EncryptedData.rds", make sure top open that file. The `encrpyt()` function changes your data. It does not have any effect on what the saved file name will be. If you aren't using `encrypt_file`, the file name will not change.

Comment: Thanks! This works! Do you know if there is a way to store and call the password from a file so that I don't have to manually enter it for each column when decrypting?